# Play audio automatically when a div loads

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an HTML page with multiple divs, each div loading on the next button click. I need to play audio automatically when a div loads. And stop/pause the previous audio on next div loads. How to do this?

```js
<script>
  function next() {
    var qElems = document.querySelectorAll("#questions>div");
    for (var i = 0; i < qElems.length; i++) {
      if (qElems[i].style.display != "none") {
        qElems[i].style.display = "none";
        if (i == qElems.length - 1) {
          qElems[0].style.display = "block";
        } else {
          qElems[i + 1].style.display = "block";
        }
        break;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

```css
  * {box-sizing: border-box;}
    .column {float: left; width: 50%; padding: 10px;}
    .row: after {content: ""; display: table; clear: both;}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="questions">
    <div class="row" id="d002" style="display: none;">
      <hr />
      <div class="column" style="text-align: center;">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/img_02.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <audio src="audio/02.mp3" controls></audio>
        <p>Long time ago, .....</p>
      </div>
      <div style="text-align: right;">
        <button onclick="next()">Next</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="d003" style="display: none;">
      <hr />
      <div class="column" style="text-align: center;">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/img_03.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <audio src="audio/03.mp3" controls></audio>
        <p>One .... lived nearby.</p>
      </div>
      <div style="text-align: right;">
        <button onclick="next()">Next</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Pls help

**Update:** I made some changes. Now I can autoplay the first audio-only. How to apply these for all audio. Also, I am unable to stop the previous audio.

- added inside audio tag:  `onloadeddata="this.play();" playsinline muted controls></audio>`
- and inside `next()` : `document.getElementById("myAudio").muted = false;`

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Title</title>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function next() {
    var qElems = document.querySelectorAll("#questions>div");
        for (var i = 0; i < qElems.length; i++) {
            if (qElems[i].style.display != "none") {
            qElems[i].style.display = "none";
            if (i == qElems.length - 1) {
                qElems[0].style.display = "block";
        
            } else {
                qElems[i + 1].style.display = "block";
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("myAudio").muted = false;
}
</script>
<style>
@font-face {font-family: 'manjari'; src: url('font/manjari.ttf') format('truetype'); font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;}
body {font-family: manjari; font-size: 38px;}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.column {float: left; width: 50%; padding: 10px;}
.row: after {content: ""; display: table; clear: both;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="questions">
 <div class="row" id="d001">
 <hr>
 <div class="column" style="text-align: center;"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/img_01.jpg"></div>
 <div class="column">
 <audio src="audio/01.mp3" controls autoplay></audio>
 <h2>title</h2>
 <p>text</p>
 </div>
 <div style="text-align: right;"><button onclick="next()">Next</button></div>  
 </div>
<div class="row2" id="d002" style="display: none;">
 <hr>
 <div class="column" style="text-align: center;"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/img_02.jpg"></div>
 <div class="column">
<audio id="myAudio" src="audio/02.mp3"  onloadeddata="this.play();" playsinline muted controls></audio>
 <p>some text</p>
 </div>
 <div style="text-align: right;"><button onclick="next()">Next</button></div>
 </div>
<div class="row" id="d003" style="display: none;">
 <hr>
 <div class="column" style="text-align: center;"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/img_03.jpg"></div>
 <div class="column">
 <audio id="myAudio" src="audio/03.mp3"  onloadeddata="this.play();" playsinline muted controls></audio>
 <p>some text...</p>
 </div>
 <div style="text-align: right;"><button onclick="next()">Next</button></div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the doubt is:

- How to apply this autoplay for all audio, and in chrome browser?
- How to stop the previous audio when one is playing?

Comment: Have you tried using the `play` method ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play))?

Answer (score 0):

As jQuery is included in the HTML, using it to modify the `next` function

```
<script>
    function next(){
      if($(this).closest('.row').next('.row').length){
        $(this).closest('.row').find('audio')[0].pause();
        $(this).closest('.row').hide();
        $(this).closest('.row').next('.row').show();
        $(this).closest('.row').next('.row').find('audio')[0].play();
      }
    }
</script>
```

Now, the first element can be taken care of in two ways. First, you can include this at the end of `body` element

```
 <script>
    $('.row#d002').show();  // using d002 id here, replace it with id of first element with class='row'
    $('.row#d002').find('audio')[0].play();
</script>
```

Else you can add `autoplay`  attribute in the first `audio` element, and remove `display:none` from the first element with `class='row'`

Comment: Hi, It's disabled click & show div function, also audio not playing.